# GCloud with Jenkins - gcloud command is not working

Tags: jenkins, gcloud, firebase-test-lab

I am following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/continuous) and I was able to work on almost all of it except the last part where Jenkins will execute a GCloud command after app Gradle build is complete and generates a debug apk.

[image]

I can execute GCloud commands with default console anywhere since its environment path was set during initial installation, but Jenkins although running locally cannot execute GCloud commands.

[image]

This is the error of the workspace

[image]

**UPDATE**

I move the build command from "Execute shell" to "Execute Windows batch command" but still cannot recognize

```
'gcloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I read already numerous SO related question but none of it works on me, one is by changing Jenkins service Log On but I cannot start it after doing that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to see the images due to org restrictions so ignore me if you have already done this..

- check if gcloud is installed properly
- set the path to gcloud in your PATH variable for Linux machine
- set 'environment variables on windows machine.. I have set these on my machine..

> CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = path to working python exe
>
> GCLOUD_HOME = folder where gcloud relates exe files are stored

I hope this solves your problem.